# python & numpy: sum of an array slice

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 1-dimensional numpy array (`array_`) and a Python list (list_).

The following code works, but is inefficient because slices involve an unnecessary copy (certainly for Python lists, and I believe also for numpy arrays?):

```
result = sum(array_[1:])
result = sum(list_[1:])
```

What's a good way to rewrite that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Slicing a numpy array *doesn't* make a copy, as it does in the case of a list.

As a basic example:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(100)
y = x[1:5]
y[:] = 1000
print x[:10]
```

This yields:

```
[   0 1000 1000 1000 1000    5    6    7    8    9]
```

Even though we modified the values in `y`, it's just a view into the same memory as `x`.

Slicing an ndarray returns a view and doesn't duplicate the memory.

However, it would be much more efficient to use `array_[1:].sum()` rather than calling python's builtin `sum` on a numpy array.

As a quick comparison:

```
In [28]: x = np.arange(10000)

In [29]: %timeit x.sum()
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.2 us per loop

In [30]: %timeit sum(x)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.01 ms per loop
```

Edit:

In the case of the list, if for some reason you don't want to make a copy, you could always use `itertools.islice`.  Instead of:

```
result = sum(some_list[1:])
```

you could do:

```
result = sum(itertools.islice(some_list, 1, None))
```

In most cases this is overkill, though. If you're dealing with lists long enough that memory management is a major issue, then you probably shouldn't be using a list to store your values.  (Lists are not designed or intended to store items compactly in memory.)

Also, you wouldn't want to do this for a numpy array. Simply doing `some_array[1:].sum()` will be several orders of magnitude faster and won't use *any* more memory than `islice`.

Comment: There must be something odd in your machine. According to my timings `sum(x)` is just some 5- 10% slower than `x.sum()` (on `numpy 1.5.1`). Thanks

Comment: @eat - Are you using relatively large (>1000 elements) arrays?  With short (~10 element) arrays, sum is only a few percent slower, but by the time you get up to >1000 elements, it's a matter of microseconds vs milliseconds. I've run it on 3 machines with different hardware and different versions of python & numpy. The times differ, but the scaling results are similar. They're both linear-time algorithms, but iterating through every element of a numpy array in python (which is what sum does) is much slower than iterating through every element of the memory buffer in C (which is what numpy does)

Comment: No, same size as yours. I'll abuse the answer for a while to show my timings. Thanks

Comment: how did you call command-line timeit in [29] and [30] from within the shell? Did you start a subshell?

Comment: @max - It's one of IPython's "magic" functions.  http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/  It's just more convienent that putting a full `timeit.timeit` call with setup, etc... All it does is use the code previously run in the interactive shell as the `setup` kwarg to `timeit.timeit`.  If you aren't already using IPython, have a look at it! It has many nice little features and macros!

Answer (score 8):

My first instinct was the same as Joe Kington's when it comes to lists, but I checked, and on my machine at least, `islice` is consistently slower!

```
>>> timeit.timeit("sum(l[50:950])", "l = range(1000)", number=10000)
1.0398731231689453
>>> timeit.timeit("sum(islice(l, 50, 950))", "from itertools import islice; l = range(1000)", number=10000)
1.2317550182342529
>>> timeit.timeit("sum(l[50:950000])", "l = range(1000000)", number=10)
7.9020509719848633
>>> timeit.timeit("sum(islice(l, 50, 950000))", "from itertools import islice; l = range(1000000)", number=10)
8.4522969722747803
```

I tried a `custom_sum` and found that it was faster, but not by much:

```
>>> setup = """
... def custom_sum(list, start, stop):
...     s = 0
...     for i in xrange(start, stop):
...         s += list[i]
...     return s
... 
... l = range(1000)
... """
>>> timeit.timeit("custom_sum(l, 50, 950)", setup, number=1000)
0.66767406463623047
```

Furthermore, at larger numbers, it was slower by far!

```
>>> setup = setup.replace("range(1000)", "range(1000000)")
>>> timeit.timeit("custom_sum(l, 50, 950000)", setup, number=10)
14.185815095901489
```

I couldn't think of anything else to test. (Thoughts, anyone?)

Comment: Well, I wasn't claiming it was faster (there's no reason it would be). (I am surprised at how much slower it is, though...) I was claiming that it would use less memory, as it wouldn't make a copy of the list. It does do that.

Comment: @Joe, sorry, I assumed you were talking about speed.

Comment: Well, re-reading my post, it certainly seems that way!  I meant memory usage, but that wasn't at all clear from what I wrote. I'm an intrigued at how much difference there is... Oddly enough, with large enough lists, it appears that `islice` becomes faster again... You need ~1e7 elements, though. I'd imagine that at that point allocating new memory becomes a bottleneck.  At any rate your post is certainly an interesting comparison!

Answer (score 3):

@Joe Kington (this is temporary answer to just show my timings, I'll remove it soon):

```
In []: x= arange(1e4)
In []: %timeit sum(x)
100000 loops, best of 3: 18.8 us per loop
In []: %timeit x.sum()
100000 loops, best of 3: 17.5 us per loop
In []: x= arange(1e5)
In []: %timeit sum(x)
10000 loops, best of 3: 165 us per loop
In []: %timeit x.sum()
10000 loops, best of 3: 158 us per loop
In []: x= arange(1e2)
In []: %timeit sum(x)
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.44 us per loop
In []: %timeit x.sum()
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.2 us per loop
```

As far as my numpy(1.5.1) source tells, `sum(.)` is just a wrapper for `x.sum(.)`. Thus with larger inputs execution time is same (asymptotically) for `sum(.)` and `x.sum(.)`.

**Edit**: This answer was intended to be just a temporary one, but actually it (and its comments) may indeed be useful to someone. So I'll just leave it as it is just now, until someone really request me to delete it.

Comment: @eat: I think the OP's code and Joe's timings use the built-in `sum()` rather than `numpy.sum()`.  This is only one of the pitfalls of using `from numpy import *`.

Comment: @eat - Yes, I was purposefully comparing python's `sum` to numpy's `sum`. I assumed the OP was referring to python's `sum`, as well. (He very well may not have been...)  I have to agree with @Sven, here... This is exactly why `from whatever import *` is bad, and why it's especially bad in the case of a namespace as large as numpy's! :)

Comment: Aha, OK that makes (kind of) sense. However I personally feel quite comfortable to work with `IPython` profile `scipy`, even tough it shadows `pythons sum(.)`. (And since Joe was using `IPython` as well, I just misinterpreted the timings). BTW, should I still remove this answer or leave it (with comments as further clarification of OP's question)? Thanks

Comment: Eh, I think it clarifies a point that other people might be confused on. I'd leave it if it were me... Your call, though, of course.

Comment: @eat: `from numpy import *` shadows `all()`, `min()`, `max()`, `sum()`, `any()`, `abs()` and `round()`.  The biggest show-stoppers for me (even for interactive use) are `any()` and `all()` -- the numpy versions won't work with generator expressions.  (I'd also suggest not to delete this answer.)

Comment: @Joe Kington: the OP (myself) was referring to Python's `sum` because the OP just started using numpy yesterday, and wasn't aware that it has its own, much faster, version of `sum`! Thanks for all the comments!

Comment: @Sven Marnach: Good points. My background is `Matlab` and mainly (so far) I have assessed `numpy` and `scipy` based on that. But of'course there exists the `pure Python` world as well. Anyway, it seems that naming conflicts can be avoided (quite straightforward manner) in scripts, but not (any straightforward manner at all) in interactive sessions, configured by some third party. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't find `x[1:].sum()` significantly slower than `x.sum()`. For lists `sum(x) - x[0]` is faster than `sum(x[1:])`(about 40% faster OMM).